# What is faster delete with where or delete with subquery in where?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've found a peace of code in my project

```
delete from queue where id in(
   select id
   from queue
   where date_part('day', now() - date_of_sending) >= 40)
```

I think that this variant is better

```
delete from queue where date_part('day', now() - date_of_sending) >= 40
```

Of course server will optimize both of them, but which query is faster?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that can be easily profiled and determined for this specific case, which is too localized to begin with.

Comment: did you test it yourself? in many usage scenarios it may alter i.e.  are you expecting 1 row to be deleted or all, are there 100 rows in the table or 100,000,000. if i was forced to guess however i would suggest option 2

Comment: Try running it yourself with `EXPLAIN`, the information you will see should help you to determine which query is faster.

Comment: Note: the queries are only equal if the `id` field is a primary key (or a candidate key). In other cases: YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not *only* about speed of the query, but *also* whether it is logically correct to merge sub-query into original statement.

First, you're working with one and only relation `queue` here. Therefore columns `id` and `date_of_sending` belongs to   one and the same relation. So this means your statement:

```
DELETE FROM queue WHERE date_part('day', now() - date_of_sending) >= 40
```

is a logical equivalent of the one with the sub-query, you can use it.

But this will not make your query any faster.

You're using column `date_of_sending` as a part of a function call. Therefore, for DBMS to be able to make use of indexes for this construct, you'll have to build a [function-based index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) on the whole expression. To avoid this limitation and use *possible* index on the column, rewrite (and simplify) your `WHERE` clause like this:

```
DELETE FROM queue WHERE date_of_sending >= current_date-40;
```

Looking into possible optimizations, its always good to check if there are any expression with columns and try rewriting those in such a way, that column is used in a free form — this gives much more freedom for planner to use indexes.

And yes, as suggested in the comments, `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)` is your friend.
**Be warned though**, that this will actually execute your `DELETE` statement. Therefore you'd better wrap whole stuff into the explicit transaction:

```
BEGIN;
EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)
  DELETE FROM queue WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM queue
     WHERE date_part('day', now() - date_of_sending) >= 40);
EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)
  DELETE FROM queue WHERE date_of_sending >= current_date-40;
ABORT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the database engine itself can tell you which one will execute faster (or if there will be any difference in execution at all).

However, the first one is obviously needlessly complex and therefore the second one is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

**`Where` is faster than the `Innerquery`.** In inner query case, first it will fire then main query will run. But in case of where it is filter only those rows containing `where` condition and deleting only those records.

Answer (score 0):

Warning, with the first one, you will get an error with MySQL : #1093 - You can't specify target table 'queue' for update in FROM clause. But the second works everywhere.

Comment: Question is tagged with `postgresql` and not with `mysql`, so this is not strictly applicable.